# Need to transfer data from AWS EFS to EFS in different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, aws-datasync

I have an EFS configured in the oregon region but as the EFS is now available in the Tokyo region so I want to transfer all EFS data to the Tokyo region where EFS is already created.

AWS doc mentioned AWS-DataSync but it does not work as expected to copy data from one efs to another within different regions through an agent.

Can anyone please suggest me some better solution that can copy data easily. Rsync and s3cmd are single-threaded and too slow.

I already created a DataSync agent but while creating the task it cannot show me the destination efs in the destination step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fpsync command. For that you need to install for Amazon Linux and RHEL 6:

```
sudo yum install fpart -y

time fpsync -n 10 -v -o -azr /source /destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy data from source EFS in a region and target EFS in another region.
Enable VPC Peering connection and configure the Routes accordingly.

Refer to the link below for the detailed explanation of EFS-EFS DataSync for different regions.

Link- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/transferring-file-data-across-aws-regions-and-accounts-using-aws-datasync/

Answer (score 0):

There is solution called [EFS-to-EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/efs-to-efs-backup-solution/) backup, using a lambda function and [fpsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/fpsync.1.html).